# How to add the Title tag in Image dialog in Media Browser (MODx Revo)?

Tags: ckeditor, modx, modx-revolution

I tried to add the 'title' field, but nothing helped. Where to find the answer?

[Only 'alt' tag in the dialog window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjKuH.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no options to do it in editor. So - fell free to insert any attributes you want in source code:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible to insert the value by hands. But I want to help managers to fill up alt and title tags in the dialog window.

Comment: Very strange that there are no functionality for that. And what is more strange – why this topic is receiving minuses.

Comment: This functional to anyone until that time was not necessary. No one but you. And nobody understands why you need that, because you not adding this information in your question.